# Ошибка в запросе INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql  = ("INSERT INTO news SET (`text`)VALUES ('$news')");
```

Вот запрос, в чём собственно ошибка понять никак не могу, будьте добры, подскажите.

Пробую вот так:

```
INSERT INTO news SET (text) VALUES ('".$news"');
```

Тоже ничего не выходит!

Comment: mysql_query вообще присутствует?

Answer (score 1):

Открываем гугл, вводим SQL INSERT - и понимаем что забыли синтаксис...
вообщем вот ссылка - [SQL Insert](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL))

UPD - попробуйте вместо `text` - `text`

Comment: Ну вроде синтаксис верный 

$sql  = ("INSERT INTO news SET (`text`) VALUES ('".$news."')") or die (''.mysql_error());

Выводит :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`text`) VALUES ('текст')' at line 1

Comment: Может, вы таки пойдете по ссылочке, которую я предоставил и посмотрите синтаксис SQL Insert оператора? >.<

Comment: Что у Вас сегодня с SQL-ем у всех? =) Alex дело говорит. По ссылочке пройди)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql  = ("INSERT INTO news (text)VALUES ('$news')");
```

Вообще text зарезервированное слово в мускуле, но запрос проходить должен.

Answer (score -1):

Во второй версии запроса нужно точку справа переменной.  Ну а если и это не помогает, попробуйте

`$sql = "INSERT INTO news SET text = '$news' ";`